# Is there something like NSOperationQueue from ObjectiveC in Python?

Tags: python, objective-c, nsoperationqueue

I'm looking into concurrency options for Python. Since I'm an iOS/macOS developer, I'd find it very useful if there was something like NSOperationQueue in python.

Basically, it's a queue to which you can add operations (every operation is Operation-derived class with run method to implement) which are executed either serially, or in parallel or ideally various dependencies can be set on operations (ie that some operation depends on others being executed before it can start).

Comment: Did python ever solve the global interpreter lock problem?   If not, concurrency in python is surprisingly not concurrent.

Answer (score 2):

have you looked celery as an option? This is what celery website quotes

> Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing.   It is focused on real-time operation, but supports scheduling as well.

Comment: Thanks Ashish. This indeed looks interesting. Not quite what I was looking for, but it may be of help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for it, too. But since it doesn't seem to exist yet, I have written my own implementation:

```
import time
import threading
import queue
import weakref

class OperationQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = None
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

    def run(self):
        while self.queue.qsize() > 0:
            msg = self.queue.get()
            print(msg)
            # emulate if it cost time
            time.sleep(2)

    def addOperation(self, string):
        # put to queue first for thread safe.
        self.queue.put(string)
        if not (self.thread and self.thread.is_alive()):
            print('renew a thread')
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
            self.thread.start()





myQueue = OperationQueue()
myQueue.addOperation("test1")
# test if it auto free
item = weakref.ref(myQueue)
time.sleep(1)
myQueue.addOperation("test2")
myQueue = None
time.sleep(3)
print(f'item = {item}')
print("Done.")
```

Comment: the variable "item" is to verify that myQueue will auto release itself.
because in my fisrt version, I use endless while and can't release it.
sleep(2) is to emulate that if the operation were very heavy so that cost time.

Comment: In your example, you add strings to `OperationQueue`; shouldn't you add Operation objects which have `run` method?

Comment: yes，it's brief version. it's my project currently. my complete code is more than 3 pages and I think brief version is better for teaching.