# Stopping and restarting a thread in Python/Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi

so... Here is my problem. I have a system that includes a shut down switch, which is supposed to stop all threads and turn off all the outputs.

I'm handling the switch with an exception, and the stopping of the thread (hiloS1) with a flag, called isOn. When the exception happens, I make the isOn variable False and that stops the thread. HOWEVER, when I turn the system back on, and I make the isOn variable True again, the thread doesn't start again.

I don't want to kill the thread, I just want to stop it while the System is off and having it restart when it is on again.

Here is my code:

```
import time
from firebase import firebase
import Adafruit_ADS1x15
import threading
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

''' Conversor Análogo Digital '''

adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1115()
GAIN = 1

''' GPIO '''
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

''' SALIDAS '''

#LED VERDE/ INTERRUPTOR DEL SISTEMA#
green = 16
GPIO.setup(green, GPIO.OUT)

#LED ROJO/ VÁLVULA SELENOIDE#
red= 23
GPIO.setup(red, GPIO.OUT)

#LED AZUL/ BOMBA HIDRÁULCA#
blue=20
GPIO.setup(blue, GPIO.OUT)

#LED AMARILLO/ MOTOR MEZCLADOR#
yellow=21
GPIO.setup(yellow, GPIO.OUT)

''' ENTRADAS '''

#POTENCIOMETRO#
puerto0 =0 #Puerto es conversor A0

#INTERRUPTOR DEL SISTEMA/ PULSADOR#
BUTTON_GPIO =24
GPIO.setup(BUTTON_GPIO, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)#Interruptor del sistema



''' VARIABLES DE CONROL '''

isOn=True #Variable que controla si el sistema se encuentra encendido o apagado.

'''Método que controla la variable isOn'''

def button_pressed_callback(channel):
  global isOn
  isOn = not isOn
'''
#EVENTO DE INTERRUPCIN DEL SISTEMA#
GPIO.add_event_detect(BUTTON_GPIO, GPIO.FALLING, callback=button_pressed_callback, bouncetime=100)
'''

'''Método para lectura del conversor Análogo-Digital'''
def lectADS(port):
  lect = adc.read_adc(port, gain=GAIN)
  if (lect<0):
  lect=0
  return lect

'''Método que convierte los valores brutos del conversor análogo digital a un rango definido por
sus argumentos'''
def maps(vx_i,vmin_i,vmax_i, vmin_o,vmax_o):
  valor = ((vx_i - vmin_i)*(vmax_o - vmin_o) / ( vmax_i - vmin_i)) + vmin_o
  return round(valor,2)

'''Método que define el rango de temperatura del potenciometro, imprime el valor específico
y lo envía a la base de datos.'''
def sensor(ts, port):
 while isOn:
   lect = lectADS(port)
   time.sleep(ts)
   if(port==0):
     temp =maps(lect, 0, 26416, 0, 150)
     print('Temperatura: ' , temp )
     print(band)
     bd.put('/','Temperatura', temp)

'''Función que apaga todas las salidas del sistema y detiene los hilos'''
def systemOff():
  GPIO.output(red, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(blue, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(green, GPIO.LOW)
  GPIO.output(yellow, GPIO.LOW)


#Creamos los hilos
hiloS1= threading.Thread(target = sensor, args=(1, puerto0, ))


#Iniciamos los hilos

hiloS1.start()

#Eventos de interrupción
GPIO.add_event_detect(BUTTON_GPIO, GPIO.RISING, callback=button_pressed_callback, bouncetime=100)


#MAIN
try:
  while True:
    if isOn:
      GPIO.output(green, GPIO.HIGH)
    else:
      systemOff()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
band=False
print('Terminar programa')
'''finally:
GPIO.cleanup()
'''
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [restarting-a-thread-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692250)

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. That person is killing the threads with the join function, i'm not killing the thread, i'm using a flag.

Comment: You didn't read and understand the answer. The core point is: ***You cannot restart a thread.***