# Are bare threads reusable?

Tags: python, multithreading

I've been playing around with threads the other day in Python. So generally a minimal code with threads looks like this:

```
from threading import *

t = Thread(target=some_function)

t.start()
t.join()  # optional though
```

This example shows a thread which is created, run and joined to the main thread. But after it is complete, `t` can't be started anymore. What is the point of such behavior, and can we reuse threads, instead of creating them every time we need to run something?

Comment: Would like to note that I've only recently learned about threads and how they work, so don't rely on me understanding complicated concepts right away :)

Comment: There are various libraries and built in functions to help you reuse threads, like the `ThreadPool` class in the standard library

Comment: @mousetail I see. But why can't we run thread multiple times? I want to know where this limitation comes from.

Comment: I find that quite natural. It is like a closed file, terminated process, finished TCP connection, exhausted iterator, logged-out session, dead parrot etc.

Comment: A thread is not the code it executes (which can generally reused by executing it again — possibly in another thread).

Comment: A thread can not really stay alive if it's not running any code. If you want to reuse the thread you need to have some code that waits at the end and performs some action in some trigger that can restart it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restarting a thread in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692250/restarting-a-thread-in-python)

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think yes. That gave better explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> why can't we run thread multiple times?

Because a `Thread` is not a thread. A thread basically is a walk through your code, and a `Thread` is a Python object whose methods afford you some control over that walk.

Think about taking a walk through your neighborhood. Even if you follow the same route that you followed yesterday, the walk that you took today is not the same walk as the walk that you took yesterday.

The designers of Python's `Thread` class (and also, the designers of similar classes in other libraries for other languages) arbitrarily chose to make the behavior of the `Thread` class align with that way of thinking about threads.