# Is it possible to run threads in while loop

Tags: python

I am trying to run a thread in while loop but I am getting the error `RuntimeError: threads can only be started once` kindly suggest a way to fix this

```
import sys
import threading
import time

import keyboard


def hd():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("hello")


cc = threading.Thread(target=hd)

while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
        print("Q is pressed")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        if not cc.is_alive():
            cc.start()
```

Comment: Are you trying to call `hd()` periodically, till `Q` is pressed on keyboard ?

Comment: Start the thread once before the loop. Just stop it when the Q is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this post out: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692250/restarting-a-thread-in-python). It provides some good insight into your question.

Threads are basically destroyed after they have completed. Editing your else statement to something like this might accomplish the task at hand:

```
if not cc.is_alive():
        cc = threading.Thread(target=hd)
        cc.start()
```

Comment: Doesn't this cause a thread leak? You should rather stop the existing thread, not dereference it and start a new one