# Run 1 subroutine multiple times simultaneously in threads in Python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I have a subroutine which I want to run over and over again, but in threads so it runs more times per second. I have tried using threading and using a while loop to run the threads again and again but you can't run one thread more than once.

Here is where I tried to create the threads `realCode` being my subroutine

```
checkerThread1 = Thread(name='T1', target=realCode, args=())
checkerThread2 = Thread(name='T2', target=realCode, args=())
checkerThread3 = Thread(name='T3', target=realCode, args=())
checkerThread4 = Thread(name='T4', target=realCode, args=())

while True:
    checkerThread1.start()
    checkerThread2.start()
    checkerThread3.start()
    checkerThread4.start()
```

I realise that this won't work, any alternatives would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried running?

Comment: @decorator-factory Added to the question

Comment: If you're starting threads in a `while` loop, soon you'll get hundreds and thousands of threads, which is unlikely to improve the performance :) Did you mean to start just 4 threads and then wait for them to finish? Also, what kind of work does `realCode` do -- CPU-bound or I/O-bound? (it matters because of [the GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython))

Comment: When I used a while loop it said that a thread can't be started more than once. What I want to happen is the subroutine to run. print the output then run again. realCode is requesting a api and then depending on the response printing something out. But because of the time it takes to make a request and get a response its not hugely fast.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692250/restarting-a-thread-in-python#:~:text=You%20cannot%20restart%20a%20thread.&text=When%20a%20thread%20finished%2C%20its,whole%20new%20set%20of%20everything.

Comment: @wwii Thankyou, do you have any suggestions for a alternative method?

Comment: Can you refactor `realCode` so that its execution loops?

Comment: It's not ideal but probably

Comment: After starting, continually check if the threads are alive, if not make and start a new one. `if not checkerThread1.is_alive(): checkerThread1 = Thread(name='T1', target=realCode, args=()); checkerThread1.start()` - something like that

Comment: There is also an example in that answer of a *restartable* thread subclass which might be worth using.

Comment: @wwii Such continually checking sounds like a bad idea...

Comment: @KellyBundy ... it was my first thought, it is simple to code. concurent.futures has a `.as_completed()` method that works well but I imagine it is just continually checking the threads.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly using `realCode` as thread target, you could use a target that repeatedly calls it:

```
def repeat(function, *args):
    while True:
        function(*args)

for _ in range(4):
    Thread(target=repeat, args=[realCode]).start()
```

Comment: .. That alleviates refactoring the target function to include a loop.